# Ionic 2 Storage vs Pouch DB

Tags: ionic-framework, pouchdb

Given my relational db background, I am struggling to get my head around data storage in IONIC 2. Having read numerous tutorials and articles on this, I have a general idea on how to proceed but was hoping to get some advise if I am on the right track. I am keen on using NoSQL so many of the tutorials using Ionic's SQL Storage didn't help.

So far, I am inclined to either use Ionic 2's Storage or Pouch DB. I am unable to see the difference. Both use SQLite when run as native apps, or fallback on IndexDB or WebSQL.

What's the recommended practice here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're right, PouchDB and Ionic Storage **both offer a pretty similar base functionality**:

- You can store and retrieve JSON files. Retrieving data works either by a key or all at once.
- Both can use different databases to store your data in.

But **PouchDB offers some more features**:

- [Replication](https://pouchdb.com/guides/replication.html): This is PouchDB's killer feature! You can replicate/synchronize a PouchDB to any other database that implements the CouchDB synchronization protocol. Depending on the app you're trying to build this could save you a lot of work.
- [Map/reduce queries](https://pouchdb.com/guides/queries.html): If you have a relational db background, take a second to think about how you are going to query your database. Ionic Storage only offers a `get` by key and a `forEach` iterator: How will this scale/perform if there are thousands of entries in your database? PouchDB, on the other, hand offers an API to perform map/reduce queries, to persist those queries to gain more performance and so on...

---

**TLDR**: If your use case is to store and get a few documents locally, Ionic Storage is the way to go. No need to add a new dependency and a dead-simple API. If your use case includes synchronizing to a remote database (preferably CouchDB) or includes doing complex queries on a lot of documents, I would recommend using Pouch.

Comment: I have got started with Ionic Storage now. Gladly I don't need to sync my database or perform complex queries at this point. I just send the JSON to a back-end, which then generates a PDF report.

Perhaps if this grows, I will switch to PouchDB.

Thanks!